# How can I show/access XSLT variable in Content Query web Part pane?

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I am using `Content Query` WebPart to display one item only on home page from the Posts list.

I need to display the data based on three conditions:

```
1) if "Display on home page" check box is checked
2) Based on Start Date and
3) On End Date
```

I am using this XSLT code, but it does not show up in the Tool pane of the CQWP.

How can I access these fields in `Content Query` WebPart?

Answer (score 0):

Directly access your sharepoint columns in cqwp web part by column internal name. And you can filter result in CQWP webpart directly by configuration.

i.e.

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Column1_InternalName" /><br/>
<xsl:value-of select="@Column2_InternalName" /><br/>
<xsl:value-of select="@Column3_InternalName" /><br/>
```

[Reference Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/756834/Customizing-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-and-Item-St)